# How to have progress bar update while zipping process is happening?

Tags: c#

I am creating a small WindowForm App that allows you to just choose a location and zip the current folder directory to that location. How can I have my progress bar accurately display the progress of the zip as the zip is actually happening?

I have created an array called allfiles that gets the CurrentDirectory and gets all the files. I then created a for loop that gets the length of the array and runs through it. I set the progress bar maximum to that length, and then the value to i. What would be the best to have the progress bar fill while the zip is actually running? How I have it now, it fills the progress bar first then does the zip.

```
private void Startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Zip zip = new Zip();
            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            Array allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(path);

            for (int i = 0; i < allfiles.Length; i++)
            {
                backupProgress.Maximum = allfiles.Length;
                backupProgress.Value = i;
            }
            Program.Zipfiles(filenamepath.Text + @"\backuptest.zip", path);
            cancelbackupbutton.Visible = true;


        }


public static void Zipfiles(string zipName, string addFile)
        {
            Zip zip = new Zip();

            zip.Open(zipName);
            zip.AddFiles(addFile);
            zip.Close();

        }
```

Progress bar should be filling as zip process is happening.

Comment: Well if you're trying to display progress on a per-file basis, you need to update as each file is zipped. It's pretty clear that your code is filling the progress bar and *then* zipping, but it's really hard to give you a specific answer without seeing the code from `Program.ZipFiles`.

Comment: I edited my post to include Program.Zipfiles, sorry about that. Happening in the per-file basis should go in the Program.Zipfiles method?

Comment: Yes\*. How else would your progress bar know when it is done with each individual file rather than it being finished with all of them? \*However, since `AddFiles` is zipping a whole directory in one go anyway, I'm not sure how it would be possible using this particular method in whichever particular library you're using.

Comment: One way.. use the BackgroundWorker class.  Use System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.  Do the loop in your backgroundWorker_DoWork() function like above but in the for loop, use ZipFile.CreateEntry and backgroundWorker.ReportProgress().  It should work like a charm.  Yes.. you will need to learn how to implement a BackgroundWorker.